# Multiple values from Joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have to get A.Ref_id, B.Ref_id and B_Id's Ref_id

```
Table A_B having Column_A_ID and Column_B_ID
Table A having ID, Ref_id, Name, B_Id (This is the B.ID from table B)
Table B having ID, Ref_id, Name
```

Currently I'm having the following query

```
SELECT A.Ref_id as A_Ref_Id,  B.Ref_id as B_Ref_Id, B_Id
FROM A_B
JOIN A on A_B.Column_A_ID = A.Id 
JOIN B on A_B.Column_B_ID = B.Id 
JOIN B AS Main_B on B.id = A.B_id;
```

By this query I'm getting the `A.Ref_Id` and `B.Ref_Id` columns correctly as they are showing their relevant `Ref_id` but for `B_Id` I want to have the `Ref_id` and it is showing the `B.id` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem: You say: `B_Id (This is the B.ID from table B)`. So you have a foreign key constraint there, right? Furthermore, you do a join on `B.id = A.B_id`. If so, `A.B_id` and `B.id` have the same values. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, the `A.B_id` and `B.id` are the same values, but I need to have a new column in the result which states `Main_B.id` and this column should contain the value of `B.Ref_id` instead of `B_Id`.

Comment: But you are not `SELECT`ING that column in your first row. Am I still not getting it? Sorry :)

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to select that column, can you help me in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this (right?): The value of `B.Ref_id` in the row where `B.ID = A.B_Id` while this row in turn must have `A.ID=A_B.Column_A_ID`. And the whole thing for every row in `A_B`:

```
SELECT A.Ref_id as A_Ref_id, B.Ref_id as B_Ref_id, Main_B.Ref_id
FROM A_B
JOIN A ON A_B.Column_A_ID = A.Id 
JOIN B ON A_B.Column_B_ID = B.Id 
JOIN B AS Main_B on Main_B.id = A.B_id;
```

(Last line of code with the important correction which was proposed by @Mojtaba)

Answer (score 0):

So far, I see the `ON` condition of the last join has to use the alias name of table `B`:

```
SELECT A.Ref_id as A_Ref_Id,  B.Ref_id as B_Ref_Id, B_Id
FROM A_B
JOIN A on A_B.Column_A_ID = A.Id 
JOIN B on A_B.Column_B_ID = B.Id 
JOIN B AS Main_B on Main_B.id = A.B_id;
```

By the way, having some example in sqlFiddle could be more helpful